# What's the WordPress way to get custom HTML for child pages list (with a second relative link)? Currently running regex over wp_list_pages() output

Tags: wp-list-pages, regex

I use `wp_list_pages()` to output all the child pages of the currently viewed page. This works well enough but I wanted to add the comment feed URL with an icon next to each child page.

My solution was to brute force it with a regular expression and a cheeky str_replace hack. It works. But it feels wrong that I was not able to identify a more WordPress way to do what I did. Like say, use some sort of basic template for the output.

Here's my current solution.

```
$string = '';
$meta_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'meta',true);
$parent_meta_id = get_post_meta($post->post_parent,'meta',true);
if ( is_page() ){
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=post_name&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0&depth=1&exclude='.$meta_id.','.$parent_meta_id );
}
if ( $childpages ) {
    $rows = explode('</li>',$childpages);
    $string = '<div class="subtopics container"><ul class="om_page_list list-unstyled card-columns" style="column-count: 3;">';
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $match = array();
        if(''!=trim($row)){
            preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $row, $match);
            if(0<count($match)){
                $feedlink = '<a href="'.$match[0][0].'feed/"><img src="https://openmentions.com/wp-content/themes/openmention/Feed-icon.svg" style="width:1em;" title="Topic by RSS Feed"/></a>' ;
                $row = str_replace('<a href', $feedlink.' <a href', $row);
            }
            $string .= $row;   
        }
    }
    $string.='</ul></div>';
}
```

You can see that I cludged the preg hack into the middle to add the extra link before the link. I noticed that there is a parameter `link_before` but I could not figure out how to make that also carry the URL of the page (the feed URL is that plus "feed/"). I could have used it as a str_replace target but the string `"<a href"` does that well enough if you remember to put it back after.

Is there a WordPress native way to get the same result?